# Выполнение команды только в одном канале

Tags: discord.py

Есть такая задача, что необходимо выполнять команду только в одном канале. Например:

> Канал №1 и №2. В первом канале ничего не происходит при её исполнении, а во втором она выполняется.

Есть часть кода:

```
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
    async def startvote(ctx, arg):
        emb = discord.Embed(title=f'Начато голосование на ивент',
                            description='Ивент: ' + str(arg),
                            colour=discord.Color.purple())

        message = await ctx.send(embed=emb) # Возвращаем сообщение после отправки
        await message.add_reaction('✅')
        await message.add_reaction('❌')
        print('>>Sent message about voting of event. Name of event: ' + str(arg))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать, чтобы бот игнорировал канал №1

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.channel.id == ID: # ID канала, который будем игнорировать 
        return
    await client.process_commands(message)
@client.command( pass_context = True )
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def startvote(ctx, *, arg):
    emb = discord.Embed(title=f'Начато голосование на ивент',
    description='Ивент: ' + str(arg),
    colour=discord.Color.purple()
    )
    message = await ctx.send(embed=emb) 
    await message.add_reaction('✅')
    await message.add_reaction('❌')
    print('>>Sent message about voting of event. Name of event: ' + str(arg))
```